# Inicializar um servidor node.js e conectar ao MS SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js, microsoft

Estou começando a utilizar o node.js e desenvolvendo aplicações web, acredito que essa seja uma duvida muito básica, porém não encontrei em lugar nenhum uma solução para meu problema.

preciso conectar meu .js com o MS SQL, encontrei o seguinte código e implementei ao meu arquivo script.js:

```
var sql = require("mssql");
var config = {
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx123',
    server: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxxx'
};
// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from teste', function (err, recordset) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);

    });
});
```

Porém recebia o erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Descobri que precisava rodar um servidor node, já que a função require nao é reconhecida pelo navegador.

Rodei o seguinte código em um arquivo separado chamado server.js para conseguir ter o servidor rodando e acessar meu projeto pelo localhost:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var mimeTypes = {
     "html": "text/html",
     "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
     "jpg": "image/jpeg",
     "png": "image/png",
     "js": "text/javascript",
     "css": "text/css"};

http.createServer((request, response)=>{
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var filename = String;
    if(pathname === "/"){
        filename = "index.html";
    }
    else
        filename = path.join(process.cwd(), pathname);

    try{
        fs.accessSync(filename, fs.F_OK);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
        var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(filename).split(".")[1]];
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':mimeType});
        fileStream.pipe(response);
    }
    catch(e) {
            console.log('File not exists: ' + filename);
            response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.write('404 Not Found\n');
            response.end();
            return;
    }
    return;
    }
).listen(8080);
```

E agora, mesmo acessando a porta 8080 pelo navegador continuo recebendo o mesmo erro... Não sei mais por onde continuar, alguém poderia me ajudar ou me dar uma direção para seguir?

Answer (score 1):

Luiz boa tarde, não sei a sua necessidade mas se futuramente você precisar 
usar rotas, tenta usa o express, é super fácil e tem muito conteúdo na net.